# Where to download free (GPL and others) Java Me SDK?

Tags: java, java-me

I am trying to do my first java me project and I can't understand what are free impelemnations of java me sdk. On oracle site I found java me sdk but it is under oracle license (not GPL). However I've read that java me source codes are now GPL. Is there any projects which implemented java me sdk under GPL or other free licenses?

Comment: It looks like you want https://java.net/projects/phoneme which is GPL-2.0

Comment: @Telmo Pimentel Mota I have seen this project. As I understood it is very very old and not active.

Comment: phoneME is still being developed: http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/
I wrote the author not long ago and had him add a functionality that I would like: Being able to add shortcuts to MIDlets on Android desktops.